# Node.js Garbage Collection

Tags: node.js

Node.js will do auto garbage collections ?

```
var objUser         = new Object ();
objUser.userName    = objReq.userName;
userDB.registerUser (objUser , callback) ;
```

In the above code I have "objUser" which will be passed as an argument to another class and it is no longer required in the present class. Still, should I have to forcefully collect it or will it do automatically.

To do it manually, Will NULL help or is there any other mechanism given by Node Framework?

```
objUser = null;
```

Comment: All JavaScript engines have a garbage collector. You never have to do that yourself. (Unless the engine has a bug.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node does garbage collection, but if `userDb.registerUser()` retains a reference to it, your `objUser` will *not* be collected. Only when no references to an object remain it will be collected. You usually don't need to explicitly release local references by assigning `null` to the variable — when your function returns, all local references are released automatically. You need to worry only about global references to your object.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting on this subject:  It's been my experience that objects of the same type will reuse instances. So, if you truly want a "new Instance()" of an object make sure you nullify or reset any attributes in your constructors